# Move a window and leave others where they are

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, split-window

I use Windows 10 in a virtual machine.

I want to be able to use the "split view" under Windows by shortcut. By `cmd+left` or `cmd+right`, I could move a window to the left/right half of the screen.

However, after moving, they show the resting windows on the other side as follows:

[image]

I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make them disappear.

I just want to move one window and leave the other windows where they are. Is there a shortcut I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is a shortcut for this?

I'm assuming that you mean a shortcut other than from the keyboard -- which would be the Escape key as you mentioned.

To disable this feature (Snap Assist), go to Settings, System -> Multitasking -> When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it. Turn that setting off.